# The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it because it is missing google-services.json

Tags: android

When I tried to open this application, I got an error that has:
 Searched Location:

```
C:\Users\15055412\Desktop\Applications\Instagram\app\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\15055412\Desktop\Applications\Instagram\app\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
C:\Users\15055412\Desktop\Applications\Instagram\app\src\nullnull\google-services.json
C:\Users\15055412\Desktop\Applications\Instagram\app\src\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\15055412\Desktop\Applications\Instagram\app\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
C:\Users\15055412\Desktop\Applications\Instagram\app\google-services.json
```

Which is why it does not run without google services. Can you please show me how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Please add google-services.json to root of app module folder

[image]